# What is the "Windows Update" service German translation?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update, windows-services

I'm trying to enable the Windows Update service on a German Windows Vista machine.  I tried translating "update" to German and looking for that but there does not appear to be anything similar.  Does anyone know what the German translation is.  To be specific, I'm in the services.msc window.

Answer (score 1):

The name is still "Windows Update":

[image]

If you want to use it in a script use the service name, so that the script runs in all languages.